# Does "the ground give way" mean there is no ground, only cliff?

Tags: meaning

It sounds like the video is saying (link with a time stamp corresponds the following)

> "We were in the first stage of the Everest ascent when the ground gave way, leaving me
>   swinging on the end of this rope, clutching at these black and glassy walls."

[cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/give-way) gives this meaning about "give way"

> to break, especially when under pressure from strong forces

Does that suggest there is no ground, only cliff?

Comment: The ground under his feet crumbled and he no longer was supported on a path but suspended by a rope over a drop.

Comment: @user105719 Don't post answer in comments.

Comment: @nick012000 Sorry, I know this makes me a bad cyber-citizen, but I'm not up to the documentation required for a suitable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No, it doesn't.

"The ground gave way" means that it crumbled away or broke under his feet, as your dictionary definition states. As a result of the ground breaking under his feet, he fell and was left dangling. It doesn't say anything about cliffs, just that he lost his footing.